# writing a test for "if (require.main === module) { app.listen(port); }" for a nodeJS express app

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I'm teaching myself TDD for NodeJS with Express, and I'm trying to be strict by writing tests first with Jest.

I can't really think of a way to write a test for the last 3 lines in this file "index.js":

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: 'pass!'});
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));

module.exports = app;

if (require.main === module) {
   app.listen(port);
}
```

I'm not sure how important it is to write a test for something like this, but I think understanding how to write a test for the above code might help me understand how importing with node works. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Why not using `app.listen(port)` directly? what would that conditional do?

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/endpoint-testing/ explains that I'll get a “port in use” error if I create multiple test files.  I agree the current code is probably 'over-engineered', but I'd still like to know how to test something like this if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Test #1:

- Verify no web server is running on port 3000.
- Load this module as a top level module.
- Verify that a web server is now running on port 3000.
- Kill that process.

Test #2:

- Verify that no web-server is running on port 3000.
- Load this module as a sub-module from a top level module that does nothing else but load this module.
- Verify that no web server is running on port 3000.